# Archive Manager Error

Tags: games

I'm trying to use Game Boy emulators on my laptop, but every time I try opening up the Game Boy emulator, this thing called Archive Manager keeps telling me "An error occurred while trying to load the archive." What does this mean and how do I make it stop saying this?

Comment: Archive Manager is exactly what it sounds like. It open archives like .zip and .tar. It usually gives an error like this when you try to open either a corrupt archive, or something that isn't an archive. Please include more details like what type of file it is (right click | properties), and what the program is.